Checking for an increase in outliers over time
I've been asked to test if there has been an increase in the number and size specifically of the high outliers over the years. The purpose is to show that there are more and higher extreme cases as time goes on (while the base remains the same).
I have many examples and comparisons between years, age groups and gender, but I will only show one below. There two groups of data, aptly named group1 (2022) containing a sample size of 207 and group2 (2023) containing a sample size of 250. The y axis variables are measured as integers.
Firstly, a t-test was performed indicating that there has been a decrease in the mean.

A box plot was done to visualise this
It should be noted that group2 has 9 points above 10 (approx. the group 1 upper bound) and group2 has 10 points about 10 (12 high outliers total), where the top outliers are higher in group2 than in group1. All outliers have been rigorously checked to confirm that they are valid datapoints.

And a scatter plot of var over date was done for sanity. The red line is indicative of the upper bound of the box plot, in which any point above is considered an outlier.

These indicate that there is a decrease in the mean / median, however the argument that I have been asked to statistically confirm if there are both more and higher outliers in 2023 regardless of the behaviour of the mean. I've been asked to show this across various sex, age and gender groups, and it is more visible in some than in others.
How would I go about statistically testing this?
[edits: 'sample size of', no mean in box plot]

Maybe you could test some percentile instead of the mean, for ex. the 90-th percentile or the average of the top 10%.

This is a bundle of comments rather than a coherent, definite answer, which I don't think is yet possible on the information supplied.
Perhaps the most important point is the most general: what to you would count as an outlier and why is their frequency of concern?
In one sense, outliers could be points that don't belong in a study or are quite wrong. Recently I encountered a real example of a reported latitude 10267 degrees South, which fortunately could be corrected to 10.267 degrees South given ancillary information.
However, more often in my experience, an outlier is   just a value that is surprising in view of a tentative statistical model, and the answer may be to change the statistical model, say to regard the Poisson distribution as a reference distribution, not the normal distribution.
On the face of it you have a counted outcome with integer values 0 up. The mean and median seem to be of the order of 2 or 3 and values over 20 are evidently quite possible.

Is there an upper limit to what is possible?
If so, we need to know what it is to give better advice.

Are there formal or informal grounds to regard any particular interval of values as outliers, say above 20 or above 30? Such grounds may go along with recognising that a threshold may be at least a little arbitrary.

What practical importance would outliers have? Outliers are not necessarily qualitatively different; they may be just a little or a lot larger than most other values (or smaller, in other contexts).


Your skewed counted distributions are not a set-up where standard t-tests seem to me a natural start, even relying on a central limit theorem to yield normal distributions of sample means and having large sample sizes.
Your different example results rather underline that different questions have different answers. The t test compares means, but the lower mean in 2023 than 2022 goes along with 3 (or more) values over 20 in 2023 and 2 (or more) in 2022.
Box plots (at least by default in any statistical environment I know about) do not show means. It seems a little strange to me -- although it is remarkably common -- to present default box plots as adjuncts to tests on means. (Again, in any decent statistical environment it should be easy to  show means as well.)
Much more seriously: The Tukey convention of plotting data points separately on a box plot if and only if they are more than 1.5 IQR from the nearer quartile was never intended as a rigorous or formal definition of an outlier. It's documented that Tukey chose 1.5 as a rule of thumb because (in his words) 1 would be too small and 2 too large -- and his context was one where only pen and paper and mental arithmetic were assumed available. It is alarming that this rule of thumb for visualization has hardened in some hands to a more rigid criterion. Indeed, Tukey would have been the first to emphasise that the treatment of skewed distributions like yours should include re-expression (transformation) to a more appropriate scale (say, square roots).
Detail (of possible small importance): With your graph design some over-plotting is possible as the same integer count will be plotted in the same place. I would much prefer quantile plots for your set-up.
Detail (of slight interest but no importance to your question): There is a small clash of jargon here. Statistical people tend to say "a sample size of 207" (or 250 or whatever). Subject-matter people may say "207 samples" (or 250 or whatever),  particularly if the sample is of water, sediment, rock, wood, blood or some other physical, chemical, or biological substance.

On reading this, 'outlier' is the incorrect terminology and shouldn't be the focus of what I'm looking for, and that that Tukey's 1.5 IQR is not optimal for this situation. As an attempt to re-articulate, would it make more sense to say that I'm looking for the best test to discern if the highs between years get higher?
I don't have formal or informal limits, or upper bounds. I can definitely make quantile plots, but I don't know what quantiles to pick and test?

It's hard for me to give precise advice. You haven't really addressed any of my questions.  I don't even have a sense of whether you have data only for two years, or for many more.

For 'what to you would count as an outlier', I was trying to say that it's more about increasing values. The y axis is measuring the count of a type of lesion and I have data dating back to 2017. I've been asked to see if different events in time caused increases in lesions / lesion volumes in various populations. This is why I've been asked to test for base of 0 lesions would stay the same but look for the highs getting higher but the mean remains low (and thus the data is skewed). It is also why I've grouped the data into before / after a date.

It's entirely credible that you have one outcome, several predictors and various questions to answer, but that means that there can't be a single, simple analysis that others can recommend. For example, I have no idea, for example, whether a division into years is fundamental or a matter of convenience. You've not come back on @Peter Flom's similar remark.

Adding to Nick's excellent answer, I have some additional issues of concern. These get too long for a comment.
First, while the t-test does compare means, the box plot does not formally compare anything, but the line in the middle is a median, not a mean.
Second, since you are concerned about outliers, comparing means might not be ideal.
Third, your scatterplot shows a range of dates. If you have data occurring steadily over time, then why divide it into years? There might be some substantive reason for doing this, but I think it's probably an arbitrary division, why not leave time continuous?
Fourth, I am also concerned about your "many examples". If you wind up doing some kind of statistical test, then this seems like a recipe for type-1 errors (although I am not sure a test is what you want.)
Fifth, purely from eyeballing the scatterplot, it looks like outliers increase in the middle of each year.
So .... what to do? First, answer the questions Nick asked, in particular, you need to define "outlier" for your own purposes. There is no general agreement on a definition. Then you may be able to pick a good analysis.
One possibility is to plot the 90th (or 95th, or whatever) percentile over time. You could do this with a quantile regression that included a spline of time (and maybe other covariates).

Indeed on all points. I guess that the data are weekly. I've never seen weekly data that weren't worth checking for seasonality.
